# Which approach to find multiple totals more closely follows the functional programming paradigm?

Tags: functional-programming

Say you have an array of objects with the structure like {id: 1, type: 'A', value: 10} want to find the total of type A, type B, and type C.

It would be more efficient to initialize the total variables and then loop through the array once, adding the the total variables based on type, than to use a reduce function for each total, in effect looping over the array 3 times.

However, from what I understand from the functional programming paradigm, functions should not manipulate anything outside of it internal scope and functions should have just one purpose, so the latter approach would be preferred.

Approach 1: initialize a variable for each of the three types, loop once and add to each total based on type

Approach 2: use reduce function for each total type.

Which one is preferred?

Comment: Which language are you using? You can reduce a record containing the three values in if you want to avoid multiple passes.

Comment: "*It would be more efficient …*" - what exactly makes you think that? The running time complexity is linear in either solution.

Comment: @Bergi , it's more efficient to iterate over the array just once versus three times.

Comment: @Lee , I'm using Javascript. I don't know of a reduce method that returns three values.

Comment: @StevenAnderson 3 loops with 1 statement in the body are as efficient as 1 loop with 3 statements in the body.

Comment: @StevenAnderson Lee is talking about using `{totalA: 0, totalB: 0, totalC: 0}` as the `reduce` accumulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single fold/reduce if you use a record containing the three values as the state e.g. in clojure:

```
(defn sum-inputs [inputs]
  (reduce (fn [acc {:keys [type value]}]
            (update acc (keyword type) + value))
          {:A 0 :B 0 :C 0}
          inputs))
```

then

```
(sum-inputs [{:id 1 :type "A" :value 10}
             {:id 2 :type "B" :value 12}
             {:id 3 :type "B" :value 7}
             {:id 4 :type "C" :value 40}])
```

in Javascript it looks like you can use `Array.reduce`:

```
const input = [{id: 1, type: "A", value: 4}, {id: 2, type: "B", value: 3}, {id: 3, type: "B", value: 9}, {id: 4, type: "C", value: 2}]
input.reduce(function(acc, i) { acc[i.type] += i.value; return acc; }, {A: 0, B: 0, C: 0})
```

note this mutates the accumulator record in place.

Comment: Thanks, Lee. I'm using Javascript. I don't know of a reduce method that returns three values.

Comment: @StevenAnderson - There is only a single value, a record containing the three values. I've updated the example for Javascript.

Comment: That makes sense, Lee, I see it now! Thank you.